# DbNull in strongly typed DataSet replacing with String in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I cannot figure out how to replace blanks with "". Because I am getting a DbNull error in this code:

```
var subFields = permCollection
    .Where(item=>fields.Contains(item.FBFieldName))
    .Select(a=>a.FBSubFieldName)
    .ToList();
```

Some values of FBSubFieldName are blank and some are not.
Any ideas?

Comment: `blank` means what and what's null?

Comment: I didn't say I got NullException. The exact error is: "The value for FbSubFieldName" in table is DbNull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a strongly typed `DataTable` is throws an exception(by default) if you access a property that is nullable and it is null.

You have an autogenerated `bool` property that indicates if it's null, use that with the [conditional operator(?)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var subFields = permCollection
    .Where(item  => fields.Contains(item.FBFieldName))
    .Select(item => item.IsFBSubFieldNameNull ? "" : item.FBSubFieldName)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Excellent, that works, Thank you sir! PS: Its IsFbSubFieldNameNull()

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
var subFields = permCollection
    .Where(item=>item.FBSubFieldName!=null && fields.Contains(item.FBFieldName) )
    .Select(a=>a.FBSubFieldName)
    .ToList();
```

I presume here, that according to the code provided, `FBSubFieldName` is a field of the same "data" queried in `Select`.

If this is not what you are asking for, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You need test for DBNull on the fields.
Try for starters to

```
var subFields = permCollection
.Where(item=>!(item.FBSubFieldName is System.DBNull) && fields.Contains(item.FBFieldName) )
.Select(a=>a.FBSubFieldName)
.ToList();
```